# Stripe iOS double tap to select a card

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, stripe-payments

As you can see in the gif below, is needed tap twice a card to set that card as default.

[image]

I am presenting the controller of this way:

```
let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeClient.shared)
let paymentMethodsViewController = STPPaymentMethodsViewController(configuration: STPPaymentConfiguration.shared(), theme: STPTheme.default(), customerContext: customerContext, delegate: self as STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate)
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: paymentMethodsViewController)
present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

... My delegate functions look like:

```
func paymentMethodsViewController(_ paymentMethodsViewController: STPPaymentMethodsViewController, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func paymentMethodsViewControllerDidCancel(_ paymentMethodsViewController: STPPaymentMethodsViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func paymentMethodsViewControllerDidFinish(_ paymentMethodsViewController: STPPaymentMethodsViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func paymentMethodsViewController(_ paymentMethodsViewController: STPPaymentMethodsViewController, didSelect paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod) {
}
```

It should work with a single tap. Help please.

Comment: are you using tableview for the card list? I think most likely is your code to get the card that user has clicked has a bug

Comment: No, is the Stripe iOS integration described here: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom